# Bundle different Calendars in CalDAV account

Tags: networking, calendar, caldav

I am trying to bundle all my relevant calendars into one source, i then can subscribe to with my different clients.
I have several external calendars together with the calendars I manage myself. I would like, to setup a CalDAV server which manages all my Calendars. This would allow me to just subscribe to one calendar on every device and reduce the chance of misconfigurating my devices.
Is there any reasonable way to do this or is it even supported by iCalendar/CalDAV standards?